# Android Kotlin - AdView adSize: val cannot be reassigned

Tags: android, kotlin

```
MobileAds.initialize(this) { }

val adViewBottom = AdView(this)
adViewBottom.adSize = AdSize.BANNER
```

This worked before I updated the library, now I get

```
val cannot be reassigned
```

on

```
adViewBottom.adSize
```

changing `val` to `var` doesn't solve it

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Admob 21.0.0 changed the way to set ad size directly.
You can use the `setAdSize` method.

```kotlin
MobileAds.initialize(this) { }

val adViewBottom = AdView(this)
adViewBottom.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
// adViewBottom.setAdSize(AdSize.FULL_BANNER)
// adViewBottom.setAdSize(... Anchored adaptive banner size ...)
```

Comment: Yes, for now this is the right answer, but according to their documentation a new ad banner size suppose to cover the whole width of a device if you are using java code. I don't know why it does not work in Kotlin. Using AdSize.BANNER constant makes the banner horizontally centered and it has margins on left and right.

Comment: @Yosidroid The question was about how to set any ad size but not about using anchored adaptive banner size.

Answer (score 2):

If you updated adMob dependency to`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.1.0'` And your intention is to use Anchored adaptive banner, most probably you will get that error. Here is the solution that works for me.

```
    MobileAds.initialize(this) {}

    adView = AdView(this)//instance of adView
    //get width of a device from window manager
    val display = windowManager.defaultDisplay
    val outMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics)

    val density = outMetrics.density

    var adWidthPixels = adContainerView.width.toFloat()
    if (adWidthPixels == 0f) {
        adWidthPixels = outMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()
    }

    val adWidth = (adWidthPixels / density).toInt()
    
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(this, adWidth))
```

Answer (score 1):

Set in this way

```
adViewBottom.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER)
```